# Riggin - BlenRig - Is it possible to swap out similar characters?

Tags: mesh, rigging, add-on, weight-painting

I have a fully rigged Blenrig character.  I have another almost identical character - not rigged.
Is it possible to just swap out the characters so I don't have to go through the process of rigging the second character? 
In both characters - the Verts, Edges, and faces are the same count in the hands and face, and the bodies can be scaled to be very close to the same size.  Don't know if that makes a difference? 
I know the answer is probably no, but thought I would ask before I start taking the time to rig the second character.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible. Copy your rig and move the new one into the new mesh. Select the mesh first then the armature and hit CTRL+P and select "Armature Deform". After this deselect the armature, select the original mesh and copy the vertex groups from it.[image]

Comment: Or you can do it  with the original armature too.